# What difference between StartNewAsync and CallActivityAsync in Azure Functions

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions

In Azure Functions projects we able to use two interfaces
`IDurableOrchestrationClinet` and `IDurableOrchestrationContext`, which has two of this method `CallActivityAsync` and `StartNewAsync` correspondly, to start another static function described in the same project.

Which one is preferable and for what purpose it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StartNewAsync` of `IDurableOrchestrationClient` starts the orchestrator function.  `CallActivityAsync` of `IDurableOrchestrationContext` starts the activity function.
Orchestrator function orchestrates the flow; however activity functions are the basic unit of work in a durable function orchestration. Activity functions are the functions and tasks that are orchestrated in the process. For example, you might create an orchestrator function to process an order. The tasks involve checking the inventory, charging the customer, and creating a shipment. Each task would be a separate activity function. These activity functions may be executed serially, in parallel, or some combination of both.

Read about orchestrator function and activity function at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-types-features-overview).

Microsoft docs - [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp)